# Python: replace line in file starting with a pattern

Tags: python

In a text file there is this line

```
initial_mass = unknown_int
```

I want to replace the line with

```
initial_mass = known_int
```

As the names suggest, I won't know the initial value but I want to replace whatever it is with a known value. Using Python, how do I search for a line that starts with 'initial_mass', then replace the entire line with 'initial_mass = known_int'?

I am thinking along the lines of

```
import fileinput
    for line in fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=True):
    line=line.replace(old, new)
    print(line),
```

How can I set `old` to the line containing `initial_mass = uknown_int`?
I have looked at `startswith()` but I don't know how to use that to get what I want. I've also tried regex and find it utterly confusing.

The file is not particularly large, but I will need to iterate over this process many times.

Comment: Perhaps this kind of thing would be easier with sed/awk

Comment: I am unfamiliar with sed/awk. I also find sed utterly confusing. Could you write with commentary the code you are thinking would achieve the same purpose?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't need to know what `old` is; just redefine the entire line:

```
import sys
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input([filename], inplace=True):
    if line.strip().startswith('initial_mass = '):
        line = 'initial_mass = 123\n'
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Comment: This is not working for me. The code compiles but no changes are made in the file.

Comment: To note, the unknown and known values are part of the string, and not typed numbers. I see the \n represents numbers. I tried removing it and replacing it with \s for string, but the file remains unchanged.

Comment: I tested the code on a sample file; it works for me. I don't see a plausible reason why it should not be working for you (assuming the obvious stuff like the filename is correct -- which is probably true since you do not report an OSError, and assuming the lines actually do begin with `'initial_mass = '`.) The `\n` represents a new line character. It should not be changed to `\s`.

Comment: Do white spaces count? EDIT: yeah they do!

Comment: Whitespace is important. If the lines begin with spaces, `line.startswith('initial_mass = ')` will be False. That would explain the problem. You could use `line.strip().startswith('initial_mass = ')` instead, however.